# Flujo de actividades en Django 2.1

Tags: python-3.x, django, activity

Soy nuevo en django, quiero hacer un flujo de actividades, algunos paquetes que tienen soporte en django 2.1 y python 3, django-activity-stream no tiene soporte para django 2.1. Un ejemplo no me haría daño.

Comment: de hecho soporta django 2.1 :https://github.com/justquick/django-activity-stream/blob/master/docs/source/installation.rst#supported-environments

Comment: en la documentacion oficila de activity-stream especifica que la ultima version soportada es Django 1.9 [enlace] https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html